# Need help to design inverter for 300watt solar panel

Tags: inverter, solar-energy, mppt

I have designed an inverter with PWM from Arduino and MOSFET bridge which is working from 12v, 20AH battery supply and converts it to 240v AC.

Now I have bought a 300 Watt Solar panel with following ratings

325 Watt, 9.34A Short Circuit Current, 30V Module Voltage, 45V Open Circuit Voltage.

I believe a 36V, 10AMP MPPT Controller will work.

Does MPPT outputs 12V ? So that I connect to my inverter ?

Can I connect my inverter if the MPPT outsputs 30V ? as it is not tested other than 12V battery.

I have no battery connected to PV as my intention to build a on grid solar system.

In a general, if I have a 1KVA inverter, can I connect my MPPT from solar array of 300Watt ?

I am confused what is rule of thumb here.

Please help.

Comment: Have you consulted your power company about installing a grid tied inverter? They may require it to be done by a licensed electrician.

Comment: Yes that is done here.

Answer (score 2):

> "I believe a 36V, 10AMP MPPT Controller will work."

Probably not with 45 Voc. Also, you believe while in church whereas you *measure*, *simulate*, *read datasheets* and *know* in engineering.

> "Does MPPT outputs 12V ?"

The datasheet will tell you.

> "Can I connect my inverter if the MPPT outsputs 30V ?"

The inverter datasheet will tell you. If you designed it yourself and you need to ask, you are in deep trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> Does MPPT outputs 12V?

We can't possibly know this since it depends on the particular controller.  **Read the datasheet**.  That really should have been obvious.

> I have designed an inverter ...  Can I connect my inverter if the MPPT outsputs 30V?

Again, we can't possibly know.  You designed it, **you** should know.

> what is rule of thumb here.

Don't go looking for rules of thumb.  There is no substitute for understanding what is going on, then figuring out from there.

Rules of thumb are for those that want to get a quick result that might work without having to know what is going on.  In other words, these are complicated issues dumbed down with simple answers for the non-thinking.  They can sometimes have their place, but not here where we try to *understand* electronics.